# Error validating elements stops migration or bacpac backup

Tags: sql, azure, migrate, bacpac

I am having a problem migrating a SQL 2017 database to Azure.  I have used the 'Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database' and 'Export Data-tier Application' wizards from the tasks menu in SSMS and get the same result.

I am trying migrate 4 databases.  One of the databases contains the table ItemMaster, the other 3 have views to access the table since they all use the same data.

The 3 databases that use the views to access ItemMaster, also have other views that use/reference the ItemMaster view.

When I try to migrate the data, it complains that the views that access the ItemMaster views can't find the ItemMaster view?  It looks like it is trying to migrate the views that access the ItemMaster view, before it migrates the ItemMaster view and it stops the migration before it even starts?

Here are the actual errors:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[INVHISTORY2]: View: [dbo].[INVHISTORY2] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[InvoiceHistory].[ItemMasterR], [dbo].[ItemMasterR].[ITEM_NUM] or [dbo].[ItemMasterR].[ItemMasterR].

Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[INVHISTORY2]: View: [dbo].[INVHISTORY2] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[InvoiceHistory].[ItemMasterO], [dbo].[ItemMasterO].[ITEM_NUM], [dbo].[ItemMasterO].[ItemMasterO] or [dbo].[ItemMasterR].[ItemMasterO].

Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[INVHISTORY2]: View: [dbo].[INVHISTORY2] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[InvoiceHistory].[ItemMasterR], [dbo].[ItemMasterO].[ItemMasterR], [dbo].[ItemMasterR].[DESCR] or [dbo].[ItemMasterR].[ItemMasterR].

Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[INVHISTORY2]: View: [dbo].[INVHISTORY2] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[InvoiceHistory].[ItemMasterO], [dbo].[ItemMasterO].[DESCR], [dbo].[ItemMasterO].[ItemMasterO] or [dbo].[ItemMasterR].[ItemMasterO].

Answer (score 0):

This is because **cross db queries are not supported in Azure SQL db**. Which means even if you have more than one db on a Azure SQL Server you cannot reference objects outside your db, which we could easily do on an on-prem SQl server instances.

Best possible solution to your problem is to replicate the itemMaster table to each database you are planning to migrate to remove any dependency.